# A question about persistentStoreDescriptions‘s configuration

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I will use persistentStoreDescriptions in many occasions to configure my Coredata. for example one description is used to synchronize cloudkit and another is set to be stored locally.

For persistentStoreDescriptions I do it in the Model Editor provided by Xcode. But I always had a question.

```xml
    <configuration name="local" usedWithCloudKit="YES">
        <memberEntity name="Student"/>
    </configuration>
    <configuration name="memory">
        <memberEntity name="Teacher"/>
    </configuration>
```

In the .xcdatamodeld file, in the configuration it is possible to see which Entities are included and which use use Cloudkit, but I can't see from the container, store, coordinator, persistentStoreDescriptions and NSManagedObjectModel objects to get any relationship between the configuration and the entity.

I'm just curious if it's possible to see this in the code, or if it's just another piece of Apple's black magic.

Comment: [entities(forConfigurationName:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectmodel/1506693-entities) will tell you which entities belong to a given configuration, but I can't see any way to determine which configurations use CloudKit.

Comment: You are right.Thanks!  I wander why I didn't notice this API.